# Style for each point of a polygon in OpenLayers Vue.Js

Tags: vue.js, openlayers

I try to add some style to my polygon with OpenLayers:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html

But I don't find anything on : How I can add some style to each point of a polygon.

I tried to have circles for each point but I don't know how to do that.

If someone can help me :)

Thanks :)

Comment: See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/polygon-styles.html

Comment: @Mike, thanks, but nothing on Draw mode. And in this example they give the coordinate of each points. When I draw a polygon I don't know the coordinates of each points.

Comment: You don't need to know the coordinates, the geometry function gets them from the feature.  If you make it the style for the Draw interaction the only change needed is to check that there are coordinates (as there won't be any where the before drawing starts) https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-and-modify-features-v23e6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openlayers accept multiple styles in an array for a layer.

In the code snippet below you see that `setStyle` function returns an array of two styles. One representing the polygon and one representing the polygon's corners with a callback function for geometry that returns a custom geometry (polygon's corner in this case)

```js
layer.setStyle(feature => {
      const styles = [new Style({
        fill: new Fill({
          color: 'rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5)'
        }),
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: 'black',
          width: 3
        })
      }),
      // adding style for polygon corners
      new Style({
        image: new Circle({
          radius: 5,
          fill: new Fill({
            color: 'white'
          }),
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: 'black',
            width: 3
          })
        }),
        // telling openlayers to extract corner geometries for styling purpose 
        geometry: (e) => {
          const coordinates = e.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0]
          return new MultiPoint(coordinates)
        }
      })]
      return styles
    })
```